# Moving the .git directory wihout moving the files

Tags: linux, git, version-control, configuration-management

I am using to track changes to some linux system files (/etc/*), I had the .git in /etc
but now I decided to move it to / as I want to track files that are outside /etc (both /etc and / are in the same filesystems...), I did that and tried to re-add the same files with:

```
git add $(git status | awk '/deleted/ { print "etc/"$3 } ')
```

But it does not appear to be working as I hoped as now the are two lists one with a list of "new files" and one with a list of "deleted files", if commit now I will lose all the history
for the files....

What would have been the correct steps?

Thanks!
Antonio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git subtree` ([installation instructions](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/INSTALL) if not already installed).

Create a new repository at `/` and merge it with the existing one in `/etc`:

```
$ cd /
$ git init
$ git subtree --prefix etc /etc master
```

Comment: definitively the best solution, but I don't have subtree and couldn't install it...

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it comes with Git on OS X when installing via Homebrew and with msysGit for Windows. What version do you have?

Comment: It's an older linux server with 1.6.2.2

Comment: Ah OK, `subtree` was added in Git 1.7.11.

Answer (score 2):

Ther are similar questions on SO:

[My Git repository is in the wrong root directory. Can I move it? (../ intead of ./)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918111/my-git-repository-is-in-the-wrong-root-directory-can-i-move-it-intead-of)

[Moving a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949036/moving-a-git-repository)

And there is no way of chaning directory without losing history of files.

Comment: well that was essential to my question... without that I am fine using my "way"!