# How can I make an inital push in my new repository?

Tags: git, github

I have created a new repository on github:

[image: new repository]

I clicked button to sync it with my PC (Windows):

[image: github web UI]

The `.git` folder appeared somewhere else than I wanted (nobody asked me actually):

[image: .git folder on wrong place]

So, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7949056/607407), I cut the folder and pasted it wherever I wanted. Then I restarted the Github GUI. After playing around I discovered it doesn't work any more it did hlaf a year ago: It doesn't do anything but also doesn't tell you what's wrong. I just see this forever:

[image: .git UI stuck when publishing]

I really need to set this up, so I didn't give up and started the Powershell console instead. The console is also very funny, as every command takes more than 1 second to execute. But at least it communicates with me:

I navigated to the project folder:

```
C:\MYSELF\programing\unity\PROJECT_NAME [master]> git commit
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is confusing - I have no files uploaded, yet it claims that there's nothing to do. So I tried to configure the target for the repository and pasted this command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Again, no success.

What should I do? Why is GitHub setup so comlicated? What am I missing to make it easy thing?

Comment: Do you have any files except the .git directory in the `PROJECT_NAME` directory?

Comment: Yeah, the project files that are supposed to be uploaded on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting changes from your local directory into the remote repository involves three steps

1. Stage the changes using `git add <file>`
2. Commit the change using `git commit`
3. Push the change up to GitHub using `git push`

The message you are getting (nothing to commit) means that there are no staged changes (step 1).

Note that after step 2 the change will be in your local history but not in the remote repository. This is a common gotcha as the meaning of 'commit' deviates from the naming commonly used in tools like svn.